# Visual Studio Code "debug.javascript.usePreview" Unknown Configuration Setting

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

The new [built-in javascript debug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug) extension in VSCode does not hit breakpoints for node v8.* for me. Breakpoints stay unbound. Everything worked before and I want to use the old [node debugging extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.node-debug2). I've seen people recommending to just set `"debug.javascript.usePreview": "false"`, but VSC 1.60.0 says that it is an unknown configuration setting.

How can I revert to the old node/javascript debugger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`debug.javascript.usePreview` is no longer available starting from VSCode 1.60.0.

Use `"type": "legacy-node"` or `"type": "legacy-chrome"` in your `launch.json` as mentioned here [1.60 Changelog — Javascript Debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_60#_javascript-debugging).

Comment: I get `Please use type chrome instead(2). The debug type is not recognized. Make sure that you have a corresponding debug extension installed and that it is enabled`. Maybe it has changed in v 1.75?

Comment: @Timo Do you have [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.node-debug) installed?

Comment: Thanks, in the description of the linked extension, I read `Node.js debugging support (versions < 8.0)`. I have Node 19, so it should not help?